# Who creates event objects and where are they created?

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling

I would like to know who creates event objects in Java? My question is not **How to create custom events in Java** rather it is who creates event objects.

For instance, a mouse is clicked on a `JButton` an event is generated which means an event object is created.

Now my question is who creates that event object and where is it created (in which method)? Is it created in the `processMouseEvent()` method or where?

Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The framework you're using (Swing) creates it and dispatches it.

Comment: Could you say me which class (or) method does it?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think you need to know this? What problem are you trying to solve?.

If you are curious then search the Java source code for something like `new MouseEvent`. If you don't find a match then it is probably done is some lower level code that we don't have access to.

You can also take a look at [Global Event Dispatching](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/global-event-dispatching/).

Comment: Could you at least say me the flow of event generation?

Comment: No, because I don't know (this information is not important to me) and you still haven't said what problem you are attempting to solve.

Comment: Basically, i am not attempting to solve a problem, it is a theoretical question that i would like to know. As in your post, _Swing handles the interaction by dispatching events to the appropriate component for processing._ which class/method does this i.e. who dispatches and who generates?

Comment: These are low level interactions with the OS.

Comment: OK. That means the event object is created in native code (like C/C++)?

Answer (score 1):

"The Event source is the object whose state changes. It generates Events. The Event object (Event) encapsulates the state changes in the event source. The Event listener is the object that wants to be notified. Event source object delegates the task of handling an event to the event listener."

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/swingevents/

Read the entire article. It should help.